# Preventing off-by-one errors with CRT secure string functions

Tags: string, visual-studio, security, msvcrt, off-by-one

As of Visual Studio 2005, the CRT has replaced most string functions with secure versions which add a size argument to indicate the limits of the destination buffer(s). This is fine, but it’s not clear how it should be used. Does it include the terminating zero? Take the following code for example:

```
…
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");
_tcscpy_s(path, MAX_PATH, filename);
…
```

Is it okay or does it induce an off-by-one error?

Comment: These functions were added to prevent buffer overflow.  So you always specify the buffer size.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I’m not asking about buffer overflows specifically (putting in too much data), but about off-by-one errors. They don’t make it clear if the size should include the terminating zero or not. For example, the remarks for [`strcpy_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx) passively imply that the size includes the terminating zero, but it doesn’t actually mention the zero in regards to the size argument. In my example, I *did* specify the buffer size, but should the `_s` function be getting `MAX_PATH` or `MAX_PATH-1` (or even `MAX_PATH+1`)?

Answer (score 0):

It'd be a failure of the API design to be MAX_PATH+/-1, as that would be confusing and lead to more buffer overflows.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-s-snprintf-s-l-snwprintf-s-snwprintf-s-l?view=msvc-170) states clearly for
`dest[10]` that `_countof(dest)` should be used, which would be `10`
So a simple `MAX_PATH` will suffice.